# absolute path parameter java

Tags: java

I am trying to get the absolute path of working directory, and pass it to a method.
I am getting the path in the form

```
C:\eclipse\workspace\file.txt
```

but eclipse must receive it in the form:

```
C:\\eclipse\\workspace\\file.txt
```

So I am doing a replace, but it works only for one char, how to modify it?

```
String path = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
path  = path.replace( '\\', '\\\\' );
something  = method.read(path+"\\file.txt");
```

Comment: you only need to use double slashes when you have a string literal in your code.    String path = new File("").getAbsolutePath();     will return a perfectly correct path. You shouldn't need to modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
path  = path.replace( '\\', '\\\\' );
```

To this:

```
path  = path.replaceAll( "\\", "\\\\" );
```

Comment: it keeps saying `not valid constant of type char`

Comment: Yes, but they were not present in the initial answer.

Answer (score 0):

try using the [replaceAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Just use double quotes to represent more than one char. It's then called a `String`.

```
path = path.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Note that [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) requires a minimum of Java 1.5 to work.

#### See also:

- [The Java Tutorials - Learning the language - Strings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
public String replaceAll(String regex,
                     String replacement)
```

> Replaces each substring of this string
>   that matches the given regular
>   expression with the given replacement.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the current working directory, the simplest approach is this:

```
String currentdir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Comment: and to pass the path to method?

Comment: Yep.  It's just a bit more straightforward, standard than "new File("").getAbsolutePath();", in my personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
`path  = path.replaceAll( '\\', '/' );` it works

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help.. I ran into the same issue with the application I am building.

In my app, I basically use JFileChooser to graphically select the file I want. Long story short, the absolute path of the selected file comes back as "C:\Documents and Settings....\xCBL.xml"

The path was then passed to another class for manipulation, however it failed because of the single '\'. The fix -

```
String absPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println("File Path:"+absPath);
String filePath = absPath.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
System.out.println("New File Path:"+filePath);
```

Output:

```
File Path:C:\Documents and Settings\tanzim.hasan\workspace\XML to Java\xcbl.XML
New File Path:C:\\Documents and Settings\\tanzim.hasan\\workspace\\XML to Java\\xcbl.XML
```

Hope the above helps.